# Make a deb package that installs data under /var/www/data

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, deb, lintian

I recently set up a PPA on Launchpad for distributing my web application.
Since it's a server-app, I need to put my data into `/var/www/html` which apparently is not wanted by Lintian ("dir-or-file-in-var-www").

So far, I accomplish the task via a `postinst` script, which copies the files after installation, but there has to be a more elegant way, isn't there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a more elegant solution. A postinstall-script is allowed under certain conditions, and your package seems to satisfy these conditions. From https://lintian.debian.org/tags/dir-or-file-in-var-www.html:

> As an exception, packages are permitted to create the `/var/www` directory
>       due to its past history as the default document root, but should at most
>       copy over a default file in postinst for a new install. In this case, 
>       please add a Lintian override.

Please consult the rest of https://lintian.debian.org/tags/dir-or-file-in-var-www.html as well.

Comment: Thank you. For anyone else wondering: In my .install-file I move the data to /usr/share, with the postinst-script I determine the DocumentRoot via "docRoot=$(grep -i 'DocumentRoot' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf)" and then I move the data from /usr/share to docRoot